# Prolog: count number of unique item

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog. I'm trying to count the number of people that comment a post. I have some data like this:

```
%comment(name, post id, message)
comment(ellen, p3, 'Love it!').
comment(ellen, p3, 'How does it feel?').
comment(john, p3, '?!').
```

I used findall but I can only count the number of comment. Then the result will contain duplicate name.

```
count_comment(Post, Total) :- findall(_,comment(Name,Post,_),Comments), 
                              length(Comments, Total).
```

Is there anyway I can count the number of people who commented the post?

Solved:

```
count_comment(Post, Total) :- findall(Name,comment(Name,Post,_),Names), list_to_set(Names, Unique_names), length(Unique_names, Total).
```

Comment: Use `setof/3` and then take the length of the set as numbers of comments.

Comment: Read [this tutorial](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_12.html), particularly the discussion about *existential quantifiers*.